# Can this be done using ASP.NET URL Rewriting

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, url-routing

There are about 1700 articles listed on my website created using ASP.NET 4.0 Web Forms. These articles have a url format as:

```
http://www.mymymyarticles.com/Article.aspx?ID=400
```

I have explored ASP.NET Friendly URLs as well IIS URL Rewrite. These extensions are great but once a rule is created, they treat all url's generically.

Is it possible that I manually generate my own url string for every url that exists on my website? For eg:

I want to permanent redirect `http://www.mymymyarticles.com/Article.aspx?ID=400` to `http://www.mymymyarticles.com/this-is-a-very-long-url` whereas

`http://www.mymymyarticles.com/Article.aspx?ID=500` can be redirected to `http://www.mymymyarticles.com/article/short-url` and

`http://www.mymymyarticles.com/Article.aspx?ID=523` can be redirected to `http://www.mymymyarticles.com/very-short-url`

So you can see there is no uniformity in the url's that I want to manually generate. Basically I want full control over the url's. How can I go about this. **Will it affect performance?**

Any examples are appreciated.

Comment: As far as I can see, you would like to effectively turn an integer `ID` into a url slug? At a guess, the slug is the title of the Article? If so, I think you only need two routes, one that accepts `.../Article.aspx?ID={int}`, looks up the title of the article relating to the id and sends a 301/302 response back to redirect to `.../article/{slug}`

Comment: How do I go about it? The article/{slug} part is something I want to control

Comment: I have dynamic solution for this but your URL should be looks like `http://www.mymymyarticles.com/artid/102/this-is-a-very-long-url`, for this you have to write URL rewriting rule in your web.config file for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a way of mapping an ID to the url of the new page? If that is the case, you could probably achieve this with ASP.NET Routing. What I would do is start with defining a route:

```
var route = routes.MapRoute(
    "LegacyDocument",
    "Articles.aspx{*pathInfo}",
    null,
    constraints: new { pathInfo = new LegacyDocumentRouteConstraint() }
);
route.RouteHandler = new RedirectRouteHandler();
```

This route merely captures any requests for `/articles.aspx`, but it has a constraint and a custom route handler.

The purpose of the constraint is to ensure we at least have the ID query string property and it is a number:

```
public class LegacyDocumentRouteConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        if (routeDirection == RouteDirection.UrlGeneration)
        {
            // Don't both doing anything while we generate links.
            return false;
        }

        string id = httpContext.Request.QueryString["id"];
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id))
        {
            // No query string argument was provided.
            return false;
        }

        int documentId;
        if (!int.TryParse(id, out documentId))
        {
            // The Id is not a number.
            return false;
        }

        // Set the output document Id in the route values.
        values["documentId"] = documentId;
        return true;
    }
}
```

If the Id was not provided, or was not a number, we can't match to an existing document, so the route will be skipped over. But when the constraint is satisfied, we store a variable in the route values `values["documentId"] = documentId` so we can then use it again (without having to parse it from the query string again) later in the route handler:

```
public class RedirectRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
{
    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext context)
    {
        int documentId = (int)context.RouteData.Values["documentId"];

        return new RedirectLegacyDocumentHttpHandler(documentId);
    }

    private class RedirectLegacyDocumentHttpHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        private int _documentId;

        public RedirectHttpHandler(int documentId)
        {
            _documentId = documentId;
        }

        public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            var response = context.Response;

            string url = ResolveNewDocumentUrl();
            if (url == null)
            {
                // Issue a 410 to say the document is no longer available?
                response.StatusCode = 410;
            }
            else 
            {
                // Issue a 301 to the new location.
                response.RedirectPermanent(url);
            }
        }

        public string ResolveNewDocumentUrl()
        {
            // Resolve to a new url using _documentId
        }
    }
}
```

Route handlers perform the logic of mapping from ASP.NET routing back into the `IHttpHandler` logic of the ASP.NET runtime. In normal MVC, this would map to the standard MvcHandler which invokes controllers, but in our case, we need only to issue a redirect.

In the route handler, we grab our document Id from the route values, and create a new HTTP handler which performs the actual redirect. You'll need to plumb in the bit which you resolve what the actual new url would be (`ResolveNewDocumentUrl`), but generally it will resolve the url, if the url comes back as null, we'll issue a `HTTP 410 Gone` response to say to clients (and more importantly crawlers) that the item is no longer there, or it will issue an `HTTP 301 Permanent Redirect` with the appropriate location header to the new url.

Comment: Excellent response. I will try it out. Thanks Matthew!

Answer (score 0):

I had overcome this by creating an xml file on the server with the below schema

```
<URLMapper>
    <Code>1</Code>
    <OLDURL>%Oldurl.aspx%</OLDURL>
    <NEWURL>default.aspx</NEWURL>
    <PermanentRedirect>true</PermanentRedirect>
    <Order>1</Order>
    <Status>true</Status>
  </URLMapper>
```

Loaded this in Application_Start Event to an application variable (in the form of a datatable).

And in the Begin Request --

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            if (Application["URLMapper"] == null) return;
            DataTable dtURLs = Application["URLMapper"] as DataTable;

            if (dtURLs.Rows.Count == 0) return;

            string OrigUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Replace("'", "`");

            DataRow[] drFound = dtURLs.Select("Status = true and '" + OrigUrl.Trim() + "' like oldurl", "Order",DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
            if (drFound.Length == 0) return;
            string OldURL = drFound[0]["OldURL"].ToString().Replace("%","");

            Response.RedirectPermanent(OrigUrl.Replace(OldURL, drFound[0]["NewURL"].ToString().Trim()), true);

            return;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Abdul. Approximately how many URLs did you map. An XML file parsing is usually slow and 1700 url's would kill it.

Comment: Around 400. Bcoz xml is slow, I had to load it only once on Application Startup to minimize file IO. Didn't face any performance issue..